# Which Turing Award winners have supervised the PhDs of other Turing Award winners?

Tags: history

John McCarthy won the Turing Award in 1971 [[1](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/mccarthy_1118322.cfm)]. Two students whose PhD he supervised went on to win Turing Awards:

- Raj Reddy (1994) [[2](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/reddy_6247682.cfm)]
- Barbara Liskov (2008) [[3](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/liskov_1108679.cfm)]

What other Turing Award winners supervised the PhD theses of other Turing Award winners?

Answer (score 12):

Consulting with the [Mathematics Genealogy Project](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/), I was able to find the following thesis advisor relationships:

- [John Hopcroft (1986)](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/hopcroft_1053917.cfm) advised [Alfred Aho (2020)](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/aho_1046358.cfm)
- [Martin Hellman (2015)](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/hellman_4055781.cfm) advised [Whitfield Diffie (2015)](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/diffie_8371646.cfm)
- [Edmund Clarke (2007)](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/clarke_1167964.cfm) advised [E. Allen Emerson (2007)](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/emerson_1671460.cfm)
- [Robert Floyd (1978)](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/floyd_3720707.cfm) advised [Ron Rivest (2002)](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/rivest_1403005.cfm) and [Robert Tarjan (1986)](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/tarjan_1092048.cfm)
- [Marvin Minsky (1969)](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/minsky_7440781.cfm) advised [Manuel Blum (1995)](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/blum_4659082.cfm) who subsequently advised [Shafi Goldwasser (2012)](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/goldwasser_8627889.cfm), [Silvio Micali (2012)](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/micali_9954407.cfm), and [Len Adleman (2002)](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/adleman_7308544.cfm)
- [Herb Simon (1975)](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/simon_1031467.cfm) advised [Ed Feigenbaum (1994)](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/feigenbaum_4167235.cfm) who subsequently co-advised [Niklaus Wirth (1984)](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/wirth_1025774.cfm)

Comment: Great work! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! I, of course, can't guarantee that this list is comprehensive but it's what I was able to look up in the source.